# Showing Custom Fields on Parent Page

Tags: custom-field, customization

I have lots of subpages each having some custom fields.

I am using 2 plugins, eMembers for the membership levels, and Types for my custom fields.

I am trying to show the custom field information on the parent page. I have my code working fine. But then I tried to pull in the same data again but only show the ones with a certain checkbox ticked. I have that working as well.

But my problem is when I try and run both scripts at the same time. I only get the first script results to show.

my code is http://pastebin.com/vgeZwPxM

```
<!-- 
/////
START USER LOGGED IN
///// 
-->
<?php if(wp_emember_is_member_logged_in()) { ?>
    <!-- 
    /////
    START USER LOGGED IN - LEVEL PAID
    ///// 
    -->
    <?php if(wp_emember_is_member_logged_in(2)) { ?>
    <h3 class="grey">Top 3 In <?php wp_title(''); ?></h3>
    <?php

        // Get the page's children
        $top3 = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=menu_order&parent='.$post->ID);

        if (!empty($top3)) { //check if there are any children pages.

        //If there are....
            global $post;
            foreach($top3 as $post) {

                $url = get_permalink($child->ID);
                $title = get_the_title($child->ID);
                $topThreeInArea =  types_render_field("top-3-in-area", array("raw"=>"true","separator"=>";"));
                $address =  types_render_field("address", array("raw"=>"true","separator"=>";")); 

                if ( !empty( $topThreeInArea ) ) {

                echo "<div class='col_3'>";
                    echo "<h3><a href='".$url."'>".$title."</a></h3>";

                        //If Address 
                        if ( !empty( $address ) ) {
                            echo "<p><i class='icon-pin'></i>";
                            echo "<span>".$address."</span></p>";
                        }
 echo "<span>".$facilities."</span></p>";
                        }

                    echo "<a href='".$url."' class='button green'>Visit Website</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "</div>";
                }            
            }
        } 

    ?> 

    <div class='clear'></div>

    <?php } ?>

    <!-- 
    /////
    END USER LOGGED IN - LEVEL PAID
    ///// 
    -->




<div id="county-nav" class="listNav"></div>
<ul class="county " id="county">
    <?php

    // Get the page's children
    $children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=menu_order&parent='.$post->ID);

    if (!empty($children)) { //check if there are any children pages.

    //If there are....
        global $post;
        foreach($children as $post) {

            $url = get_permalink($child->ID);
            $title = get_the_title($child->ID);
            $address =  types_render_field("address", array("raw"=>"true","separator"=>";"));

            echo "<li class=''>";
                echo "<h3><a href='".$url."'>".$title."</a></h3>";
                echo "<div class='col_2'>";
                    //If Address 
                    if ( !empty( $address ) ) {
                        echo "<p><i class='icon-pin'></i>";
                        echo "<span>".$address."</span></p>";
                    }
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
                echo "<a href='".$url."' class='button green'>Visit Website</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo "</li>";

        }
    }

?> 


</ul>
<?php } ?>
<!-- 
/////
END USER LOGGED IN 
///// 
-->
```

Cheers
Jord

Comment: This is a lot of code. **Please simplify the problem description/code** and put the code in your question.

Comment: I've updated the post to show the code.

Sorry, though it would be easier to have it on pasteBin.

Comment: Is that any better? i've took a lot of the custom fields out?

Comment: @JordanSayner : If you code is on Pastebin the question becomes meaningless when that pastebin goes away. That is why the code should be posted here.

Comment: Good Point.

Didn't think of it like that, I have copied a trimmed down version into the answer now, so hopefully that will help in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and found three ways to solve it. Types is really hard to convince to read data out of a different post than the current one in the loop...

That's the first solution, just create a loop using [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) and get the data there via `types_render_field()` as usual. Just remember to reset the query afterwards if you're doing this before your actual loop; but i guess you know about that. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query
Inside the main loop, this is probably an almost impossible thing to do I guess.

The second solution is, iirc, to use [setup_postdata($post)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) in you foreach-loop. This does some magic that finally point `types_render_field()` into the post you want. Again, this messes with all the functions like `the_ID()` or `the_content()` and such, so you could store the old `global $post` to a tmp variable and re-set it back via `setup_postdata($tmp)`.

As the last resort, which is sometimes the least complicated one, you could just read the data manually by using [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). To find the field name, it's best to look directly into the `wp_postmeta` table. I found a couple of guides for the naming convention of the fields in the database, but after some trial and error I always ended up starting [Adminer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminer/) to look at the DB.

So, choose wisely :)